# Bind two Combo Boxes together in a data grid WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a list of items (Families) each item has inside another list of items ( Family Types )

I want to make a grid view allowing the user to select from the combo box (Families) and when he selects a family the combo box family types only shows the types related to this family only.

[image: I want to bind these boxes together]

I'm expecting when the user selects a family from family box => the family type box automatically shows only the types related to this family.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't supply code example, I will just use made up values.

Assuming these controls in GridView:

```
<ComboBox Name="Families" SelectionChanged="Families_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="1"/>
<ComboBox Name="FamilyTypes" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

And this in Families combobox:

```
    Families.ItemsSource = new List<string> ()
    {
      "Family 1",
      "Family 2",
      "Family 3",
    };
```

The code to do what you want is this:

```
  private void Families_SelectionChanged ( object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e )
    => FamilyTypes.ItemsSource = Families.SelectedItem switch
    {
      "Family 1" => new List<string> () { "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3" },
      "Family 2" => new List<string> () { "Type 3", "Type 4", "Type 5" },
      "Family 3" => new List<string> () { "Type 1", "Type 5" },
      _ => null
    };
```